# autotools: how to test a program which requires a configuration file?

Tags: autotools, automake

Assuming I have an autotools project to build a program P and P requires a configuration file F. Think P=vim and F=~/.vimrc for instance. Or P=bash and F=~/.bashrc.
(In my case P is actually a lib)

The test harness provided by autotools does not allow parameter passing to the tested programs (unless ugly wrappers are used...), so such a config file may be thought as a work around: so test1 would require configuration file F1, test2 would require F2...

So the Makefile.am for some test could look as follows:

```
#test ttt is linked with program P and will test P

check_PROGRAMS= ttt
ttt_SOURCES = ttt.c
ttt_LDAD = libP.a

TESTS = ttt

EXTRA_DIST = configs/f1.cfg
```

Now: how do I get P to load file configs/F1, configs/F2... during the tests and still to load ~/.p_rc  after install?

Programs that have such config files are very commun.... How is this hanlded properly in autotools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automake deals with configuration files through the variable `sysconf_DATA`. The user installing your package can configure the destination of the configuration files through:

```
sh ./configure --sysconfdir [newpath]
```

Otherwise, if you do not specify it, your configuration files will be installed in the default `prefix/etc`

As for using the configuration files on the tests, you can use the variable `check_DATA` to load the configuration file in the same directory as your test binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a global variable in the library code that holds the configuration file path. This way for each test case I can set a different configuration file by simply setting the global variable to the relevant file's path.